# Python invoke (fabric) sys.path manipulation

Tags: python, fabric

I have inherited code that uses fabric to run commands, after altering the `sys.path`. This used to work. But now with fabric 2.5 and python 3.7, I cannot figure out how I can persist the changes to sys.path in the task. I have:

`fabfile.py`

```
import sys
from fabric import task

sys.path.insert(0, 'blah')
sys.path.append('blarg')
@task
def t(con):
    con.run('python3 tmp.py')
```

`tmp.py`

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Neither `blah` nor `blarg` are present when running `fab t`. Reading the docs, as I understand this was a legacy behavior, but the newly available configs, context managers and wrappers don't provide me with a way to alter this, or at least it is not immediately obvious to me. Is there a way to achieve this using fabric or do I need to walk another path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't actually need that one is a prepend and the other is an append, you could do this via [the env var](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

```
@fabric.task
def t(con):
    con.run('python3 tmp.py', env={"PYTHONPATH": "blah:blarg"})
```

They will both be prepends in this case.

Comment: Thank you! literally under http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/api/runners.html::env -- also appreciate your handle